Nuance of 儀礼的な意味もある in a character's thought
*full sentence: 州牧同士、儀礼的な意味もあるのかな。
While reading a story, i met this difficult part but not sure about its meaning here. Appreciates someone who could help me understand correctly ! I could only guess something like : "Maybe between the province governors, there's also a meaning of formality" ??
Context: Main character and his party members + a province governor 公孫賛 are attending a meeting inside a big tent.
A province governor 袁紹/麗羽 is holding this meeting to create an alliance army. After her long speech and introductions , another group of vassal lord /province governor 曹操/華琳 came inside the meeting tent.

曹操「そろそろ紹介は終わったかしら？」
袁紹「華琳さん！遅刻ですわよ！！」
曹操「どうせ麗羽の長話と、覚えきれない袁家関係者の紹介でもしていたのでしょう」
袁紹「…………ぐっ」
曹操「行軍の順番は？第一の関を誰が攻めるかは決めたの？本題のどれか一つでも決まっていたなら、遅刻と認めてあげても良いけれど」
袁紹「ぐ、ぐぬぬ…………」
まあ、実際曹操の指摘の通りだもんな。
でもこの二人、どう見ても仲が良いように見えないけど……真名で呼び合ってるみたいだし、どういう関係なんだろう。
あ、でも、公孫賛と袁紹も真名で呼び合ってたっけ。州牧同士、儀礼的な意味もあるのかな。


I find it funny that you are the sole author for all the related posts.

Japanese novels are difficult, what can i say when sometime the writer want a raise

The basic meaning of 儀礼的 is "ritualistic" or "ceremonial", but in this case, it implies "obligatory", "conventional", or "token". The speaker suspects that they call each other by their 真名 not out of genuine trust, but due to some obligation or custom he isn't aware of.

so he's saying : "Maybe there's also a customary meaning when the governor addressing each other by their true name" ?

@MemoriesPlastic Yes, exactly.
